# iphone - changing the background color of several views in a loop

Tags: iphone, view, background-color

I have to change the background color of several views that have the same base name like color1, color2, color3, etc., to the same color

I could simply do something like

```
color1.backgroundColor = theColor;
color2.backgroundColor = theColor;
color3.backgroundColor = theColor;
color4.backgroundColor = theColor;
...
```

but I would rather do that in a more elegant way using a loop, something like

```
NSString *baseName = @"color";
for (int i=1; i<numberOfViews; i++) {
  NSString *tempName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%d", baseName, i];
  // now that I have the correct name of the view as a string on tempName
  // how do I reference the view which name is on tempName, so I can change its color?
}
```

thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The approach you are trying to take would work in a language like JavaScript that allows you to take a string of text and send it to the interpreter at runtime. As a compiled language, Objective-C doesn't allow this.

Instead, you need to put your views in an array first, then you can iterate through them. The easiest way would be:

```
NSArray *views = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:color1, color2, color3, color4, nil];
for (UIView *v in views) {
    v.backgroundColor = theColor;
}
```

Comment: Or without loop, `[views makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(setBackgroundColor:) withObject:theColor];`

Comment: thanks. I thought I could access the views using a string, as it is possible with classes and selectors.

Comment: @Jilouc... ah, nice touch! :D